# Python Web scraping with Beautiful Soup 3: how to get text from div

Tags: html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's what the HTML I'm having trouble with looks like,

```
<div id="id" class="class">

 text

</div>
```

Say I have a variable with the Soup in it,

```
div = find('div', attrs={'class': 'class'})
```

How do I get the text portion of the div?

I've tried some of these methods separately.

```
text = div.get_text()
text = div.string
text = div.text
```

When I run

```
type(div)
```

it is of type BeautifulSoup.Tag, but when I call any of the above methods it says that 'NoneType' doesn't have any of those attributes.

I'm able to pull it from  and

and other attributes, just not div.

I have looked at several other questions regarding BeautifulSoup, but none have addressed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem with your code. If the method is returning *None* is because the `find` function of BeautifulSoup is not finding the tag and/or the attribute. Here is some suggestions:

- Try to use the function `find_all()` instead just `find()` (it will return a list)
- Be sure that the class *class* is in the tag *div*
- Try to use different libraries with the BeautifulSoup, like 'lxml', 'html5lib' etc
- If possible, try the same code using Python 3

Here is a code that I tested and is working perfectly:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '<div id="id" class="class">exemple_text</div>'

div = bs(html, 'html5lib')

answer = div.find('div', attrs={'class': 'class'})

print(answer.text)
```

Comment: .text doesn't work, but I can use .__str__ and use string manipulation to get rid of the div tags

Comment: Yes! I always use `.__str__` and regular expressions to solve problems that BeautifulSoup is not efficient. The only problem is that regular expressions are not so simple to manipulate it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what the problem is here but here is a working example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div id="id" class="class">

 text

</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'class'})
print (type(div.text))
print (div.text)
```

Outputs:

```
<type 'unicode'>

 text
```

Comment: Yeah .text still isn't working, but I am able to use the equivalent of div.__str__ and edit out the div tags

Comment: Can you update to BS4? all development on BS3 has stopped, the last release for that version was over 2 years ago

Comment: I'll install it and give it a shot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to extract the text from the elements? Try this:

```
html='''
<div id="id" class="class">
 text
</div>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
item = soup.find(id="id").text.strip()
item1 = soup.find("div").text.strip()
item2 = soup.find(class_="class").text.strip()
print(item,item1,item2)
```

All of them giving you the same result:

```
text text text
```